# How to get user details by name

Tags: redirect, urls, users

I am new in WordPress.

I want to get user details on frontend without login in WordPress when the user types his name in browser URL **(Like example.com/{user-name})**

and hit enter, User redirect a new page like **example.com/{user-name}** or **example.com/user/{user-name}**

Please, anyone, help me how to complete this task.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you implementing this is it through API or it is a page?

Comment: I am implementing on the frontend for the visitor can access normal information about admin. Visitor hit admin name in URL then get information.

Answer (score 0):

"Users" are basically "authors" in WordPress so those pages are available at `example.com/author/{user-name}/` (with or without the trailing slash) and what you are looking for is actually to change the "author permalink base" for the URL rewrite. eg:

```
add_action( 'init', 'set_custom_author_base' );
function set_custom_author_base() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'user';
}
```

You can then add (or modify) an `author.php` template in your child theme directory to output what you would like to show of the user (but of course not sharing private user info in public URLs like this.)

Of course this is a simple example, it might be easier to do it with a [plugin like this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/edit-author-slug/) if you want to keep the `/author/` for some roles but change it for others.